# Variation on definition of logical functors avoiding power objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Without power sets in meta-theory not every Grothendieck topos is an elementary topos, Set is still Grothendieck, but it lacks power objects.

Now I am looking for a definition of a logical functor that does not mention power objects, that is as follows, if C and D are elementary topoi, then the definition of a logical functor between them coincides with the standard definition. But if they lack power objects the definition is still sensible, i.e. for a Grothendieck topos in a predicative meta-theory.

Motivation here is defining an atomic geometric morphism without requiring power objects in metatheory.

Comment: Maybe being a lex and cartesian closed functor $F\colon E_1\to E_2$, hence preserving monomorphisms, and the induced map of preorders $Sub_{E_1}(X)\to Sub_{E_2}(F(X))$ is an equivalence, for every object $X$ of $E_1$?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I don't think that latter condition is strong enough: if subobject classifiers do exist, does it imply that $F$ preserves them?

Comment: @MikeShulman hmm. I didn't check. But your answer is a nice compromise

Comment: @MikeShulman suppose the functor $F^{op}\colon E_1^{op} \to E_2^{op}$ forms a 2-commutative triangle with the subobject functors $Sub_{E_i}\colon E_i^{op} \to \mathbf{Preord}$ (so I should have said the equivalence is natural in my first comment). Or to be cleaner, look at the poset reflection, and then assume that both subobject functors are representable. Then $F$ preserves subobject classifiers, no?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I don't think so; I think all you can get from that argument is that a right adjoint of $F$, if it has one, preserves subobject classifiers, as in my answer.

Comment: @MikeShulman oh, I see it now. Weird.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a notion of "logical functor" between predicative topoi that specializes automatically to the standard notion if they happen to be elementary topoi.  But I do know a definition of "logical functor with a left adjoint" that has this property, and this is sufficient for the purpose of defining atomic geometric morphisms, since a logical functor between elementary topoi has a left adjoint if and only if it has a right adjoint, so it is equivalent to say that $f^* \dashv f_*$ is atomic if $f^*$ is a "logical functor with a left adjoint".

The definition is: if $F:C\to D$ has a left adjoint $L:D\to C$, then $F$ is logical if and only if $L$ (not $F$!) induces isomorphisms of subobject lattices $\mathrm{Sub}_D(X) \cong \mathrm{Sub}_C(LX)$.  The fact that this is equivalent to logicality of $F$ follows from the Yoneda lemma: we have

$$\mathrm{Sub}_D(X) \cong D(X,\Omega_D)$$

and

$$\mathrm{Sub}_C(LX) \cong C(LX, \Omega_C) \cong D(X,F\Omega_C)$$

both naturally.  Thus, the left-hand sides are naturally isomorphic if and only if the right-hand sides are, and the latter is equivalent to $\Omega_D \cong F\Omega_C$ by the Yoneda lemma.

In [this blog post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2018/06/atomic_geometric_morphisms.html) I used this characterization to suggest a notion of "$\infty$-atomic geometric morphism" between $(\infty,1)$-topoi.